# unzipping a .gz extention file in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, unzip

```
# Unzip the dataset (if we haven't already)
if not os.path.exists('./cola_public/'):
    !unzip cola_public_1.1.zip
```

The above code will unzip a file in jupyter notebook.
How would I do this in a similar fashion if the file was a .gz file?

Comment: you need to use gzip library

Answer (score 1):

The zipfile package works pretty well for gzip

```
import zipfile as zf
file = zf.ZipFile("/path/to/file/YOUR_FILE.gzip")
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your file was tar.gz and it contains more files, then you can use. (You need to create test folder or use root)

```
with tarfile.open('TEST.tar.gz', 'r:gz') as _tar:
    for member in _tar:
      if member.isdir():#here write your own code to make folders
         continue
      fname = member.name.rsplit('/',1)[1]
      _tar.makefile(member, 'TEST' + '/' + fname)
```

Or if your gz is not a tar file and contains a single file you can use gzip
Reference:- https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage

```
import gzip
import shutil
def gunzip(file_path,output_path):
    with gzip.open(file_path,"rb") as f_in, open(output_path,"wb") as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
        f_in.close()
        f_out.close()

f='TEST.txt.gz'
gunzip(f,f.replace(".gz",""))
```